# od Command for filenames in directory

Tags: unix, command-line

Have a quick query regarding using UNIX to output filenames within a directory.

List the number of lines in the files in
/courses/projweek/unix/items/books, sorted  by
the number of lines they contain, so it looks like this:

```
 2 fish.txt
 2 dogs.txt
 9 cats.txt
 1 mangos.txt
```

Which is easy enough.

However, how can I list just the filenames (without the line count), but **using the od command?**

```
fish.txt
dogs.txt
cats.txt
mangos.txt
```

This is easy enough with ls -1. **However, I want to achieve the same result using the od command.** I'm pretty sure this is possible using the od command, just not sure how.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Sounds like homework, which is clearly off-topic here.

Comment: it's not homework .. just a noob trying to get to grips with using Unix.

Comment: Then tell us: why would one want to do such strange thing, and why are you "pretty sure this is possible", though you yourself admit you have no idea about that? Sorry, that does not fit...

Comment: just for the purpose of mastering Unix .. nothing sinister I'm afraid! it's good to know all of the commands and their capabilities. Would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Finally! I have found another person who puts their non-homework related files in their /courses/projweek/ directory! Even if this is homework, I think you're going about it in such a way that is at odds with the unix philosophy. That is basically small programs with a very clear purpose. If you can accomplish the task with ls then use that command.

[Unix Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)

aaaand relevant xkcd 
 [You Use Unix!!!](https://xkcd.com/1168/)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to achieve the same result using the od command.

You can't (portably). `od(1)` does not read directories, only files:

```
$ od .
od: .: read error: Is a directory
0000000
```